# How to call a function in a block from another phtml in magento

Tags: magento-1.4

How do you call a function in a block in one module from another `phtml` in another module in magento? I have one `view.php` block file. It has functions inside it, like `getproduct()`. The `getproduct()` function needs to call into functions in another file, `product.phtml`, which is in another module. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please show your code that you have tried, so other's can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If both blocks is used in the same page:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name'); // get block
$block->getProduct(); // call function from block
```

If you need block in your custom page:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('block_type'); // creation of the block
$block->getProduct(); // call function from block
```

But if for you just need the current product then why you does not take it from Mage::registry?

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```